# Is Ask Ubuntu using reStructuredText?

Tags: discussion, formatting

It might be an obvious question for those who know, but I can't find an answer to it.

Recently, I started working with [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) which uses [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html). It somehow looked familiar to Ask Ubuntu's system. What exactly is Ask Ubuntu's formatting system?

Thanks!

EDIT: The following page on SO seems to suggest that it is Markdown and not reStructuredText: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help This page is similar to https://askubuntu.com/editing-help Are AU and SO using [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are AU and SO using Markdown?

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

> Is AskUbuntu using reStructuredText?

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

> `stackoverflow.com/page` [...] This page is similar to `askubuntu.com/page`

They're part of the same [network of sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites): StackExchange.

Comment: I think my question actually included this answer. Anyway, you're right and I am happy to be confirmed. Delft boven.